# How to Disable CSS Vertical Menu flyout effect

Tags: html, css

I'm newbie with HTML Lists, I am trying to disable "Hover flyout effect" and list all sub items vertically below the main item and they should remain visible , Please help me to understand what are those properties in this particular CSS which will disable this effect

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/qbg6jw9p/

CSS

```
#prod_nav {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
    border-left: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-right: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
}

#prod_nav li.top {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
    height: 31px;
}

#prod_nav li a.top_link {
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    width: 159px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    line-height: 31px;
    color: #252525;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}

#prod_nav li a.top_link span, #prod_nav li a.top_link span.down {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: url(../images/productmenu-arrow.gif) no-repeat right center;
}

#prod_nav li:hover a.top_link {
    color:#0072bc;
    background: #fff;
}

#prod_nav li:hover a.top_link span, #prod_nav li:hover a.top_link span.down { background: url(../images/productmenu-arrow-hover.gif) no-repeat right center; }

/* Default list styling */

#prod_nav li:hover {
    position:relative;
    z-index:200;
}

#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub {
    left: 170px;
    top: -1px;
    background: #fff url(../images/productmenu-leftborder.gif) no-repeat left top;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 384px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 300;
}

#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 364px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url(../images/productmenu-section-bg.png) no-repeat right bottom;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
}

#prod_nav ul, #prod_nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

/* Overwrite the above settings */
#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub ul {
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 152px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: none;
}

#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub ul li {
    background: none;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 132px;
}

#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub ul li a {
    color: #363636;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: normal;
}

#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub li a:hover {
    color: #0072bc;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#prod_nav li:hover li:hover a.fly, #prod_nav li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly, #prod_nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly, #prod_nav li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover li:hover a.fly { 
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `left` and `top` positioning on `ul.sub`. Currently the item dropdown `ul.sub` is being told to move `170px` from the left, and `-1px` (up 1 pixel) from the top when the menu is hovered over.

```
#prod_nav li:hover ul.sub {
    left: 0;
    top: 31px;
    background: #fff url(../images/productmenu-leftborder.gif) no-repeat left top;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 384px;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 300;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qbg6jw9p/2/)

Comment: Thankyou ...But I want to keep it visible in list style ... please help me to achieve this as well ....I don't need hover effect just simple static Items with sub item listed vertically ....